# Laravel route not matching pattern

Tags: php, laravel, pattern-matching, laravel-5.3

In my Laravel `routes/web.php` file I have defined the following two routes:

```
Route::get('transaction/{id}', ['uses' => 'PaynlTransactionController@show'])->name('transaction.show');
Route::get('transaction/{txId}', ['uses' => 'PaynlTransactionController@showByTxId'])->name('transaction.showByTxId');
```

In my `RouteServicesProvider` I have defined the following two patterns:

```
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('txId', '/^(TX(1[0-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d)-(1[0-9]\d\d\d\d|[2-9]\d\d\d\d\d))$/');
```

Whenever I go to `transaction/<id>` the routing works correctly, as long as `id` is an integer. However, when I go to `transaction/TX874-152268`, for example, it doesn't match any route and I receive the `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php` error.

I've validated the txId regex and it gives a full match: https://regex101.com/r/kDZR4L/1

My question: how come only my `id` pattern is working correctly, whereas my `txId` pattern isn't?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, I've tried but no luck. It looks a lot nicer tho :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the route

```
Route::pattern('txId', '/^(TX(1[0-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d)-(1[0-9]\d\d\d\d|[2-9]\d\d\d\d\d))$/');
```

I had included the forward slashes at the start and end of the string. This should not be included when passing a pattern to `Route::pattern`. Thus the following works:

```
Route::pattern('txId', '^(TX(1[0-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d)-(1[0-9]\d\d\d\d|[2-9]\d\d\d\d\d))$');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the urls are both `/transaction/{value}` it will get the last on.

If you change `/transaction/{txId}` to `/transaction/tx/{txId}` it will be clear for the routes.

Routes can only get one, so when you assign the prefix (at this time `/transaction`) to both of the urls it doesn't work.

You can also use `/transaction/TX{txId}`, in your controller you can past `TX` before the `txId` variable.

```
public function showByTxId($txId) {
    $txid = "TX".$txid;
}
```

Edit:

Remove the `/` add the start.
`Route::pattern('txId', '^(TX(1[0-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d)-(1[0-9]\d\d\d\d|[2-9]\d\d\d\d\d))$');`

Hope this works!

Comment: That shouldn't matter, right? I'm doing the exact same thing for `users/{id}` and `users/{username}` with the regex `[0-9]+` and `[A-Za-z]+`, respectively, and this works.

Comment: I agree, but lets try it. If its works its nice ;) @pbond Btw, pay.nl is een goede betalingsprovider ;)

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but no luck: I've adjusted the regex to not match the `TX` part anymore, and prepended `TX` in `web.php` to `{txId}`, but this doesn't work either, unfortunately.

Comment: Same as before, `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`. I could add the stack trace in the original question if that helps.

Comment: Already got it, I shouldn't have included the `/` at the start and end of the pattern, apparently.